# How to have a selected value in combobox when there's only one

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm using ExtJS 4.2.1 and I know there is the `autoSelect` config option which will default to the first element of the combo's store.

But what I'm looking for is perhaps through an override, do this only when there's only one item in the combobox's store.

I thought of doing it at the store level, but then if I have 10 comboboxes in my app, that's 10 times the same bit of code...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this so far. If someone has a better idea or reasons I should not be using this method to do my override, please post.

```
Ext.define('App.overrides.form.ComboBox', {
        override: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
        onDataChanged: function () {
            var store = this.getStore();
            if (store != null) {
              if (store.count() == 1) {
                  var value = store.getAt(0).data[this.valueField];
                  this.setValue(value);
              }
            }
            this.callParent();
        }
});
```

Comment: The only "reason against" would be that the override changes the behavior of **all** combos. Do you really want that?

Comment: @Saki At the moment, I'd say yes.

Comment: All fine then. It just seemed to me quite strange to apply it to all combos. If you wouldn't want it, extend combo with the above, instead of override, and then further extend from this extension combos that do require the behavior. (Hope its clear)

Comment: @Saki Yes it is clear and perhaps extending the combo to create my own would be a better idea. I'm sure the customers will eventually come up with a reason why they'd like this behaviour not to apply in some circumstances, they always find them :)